# Increasing mouse/mousepad stopping power?

Tags: technology

Despite already having a supposedly pretty good mousepad (a QcK) and a decent gaming mouse specifically for precision, it still slips sometimes by about a pixel when I click (not everyone needs pixel-precision in their daily work, but I do). I'm not sure if it's due to the mousepad not having enough stopping power, if the mouse feet are too worn, or even if the sensor is picking up noise, but I'm wondering if there's any way to increase a mouse's stopping power/static friction without necessarily increasing its kinetic friction (e.g. pouring viscous sludge over my mousepad isn't the right way to go). DIY mouse weights? Something to put on the feet?

Comment: You mention that it "still" slips. Did you have the problem and find a fix for the problem? Is this a cumulative effect that you've noticed getting worse over time? Could it be due to inertia (mouse was still moving when you thought it was stationary?

Comment: I tried taping paper under mouse feet and using alternate surfaces (piece of wood, printer paper, et cetera), but those didn't really work very much. And I would not think it's due to inertia, because I sometimes try to test when it does or does not slip, and it sometimes slips by a pixel even if the mouse has been stationary for seconds (but if I continue to click without moving it, it doesn't tend to slip anymore, until I move it elsewhere). Pressing the mouse down helps a little, but is not very comfortable for my wrist.

Comment: What you describe sounds to me like 'noise' in the system. Alternately, if you've been trying to hack the surfaces for a while, it might also be due to wear-and-tear. A High-Tek racing shoe must be replaced much more often than a regular one due to the materials and tight tolerances. The same is true for high-performance cars (need constant attention) and computers (to optimize the system and keep it trouble free. It might be as simple as the build-up of skin cells on the surfaces and sensors from the last time it was clean. Do you wear gloves? Have a very close look with a magnifier..

Comment: You are using an optical mouse, not a ball mouse? Have you tried experimental surfaces such as different types of paper and card, etc, to eliminate whether the problem is the mouse or the mat? Oh, hang on: is "mousepad" that stupid thing they have on a laptop? If so they are perfectly useless - nothing less than an external USB mouse will do.

Comment: I use a QcK mousepad, which is supposedly a good quality mousepad, so I'm guessing it's not the pad's problem (though it could be). I use an infrared optical gaming mouse, which is also supposedly pretty good, but it is getting old. And yes, I did try alternative surfaces like wood boards and printer paper. The pad doesn't seem terribly dusty, but I'll go clean it again.

Comment: So what happened with those other mat surfaces? If you can't get stability on any type of surface, then the problem is either the mouse, the settings, or can't be solved.

Comment: Any tips for increasing the mouse feet friction?

Comment: Roughing up the feet of the mouse with coarse sandpaper might help. But I am not sure whether the problem is that the mouse is slipping or that the sensor doesn't track properly.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three solutions to the problem *"it still slips sometimes by about a pixel when I click"*.

A lateral solution could be:

- Change the mouse settings on the computer to reduce its sensitivity or motion scale.

I encounter this when editing graphics images, and another solution is:

- Zoom in to the image so that the "pixels" are bigger.

But my usual method is this:

- Place a finger of the other hand either against the mouse, to steady it, or on top of the mouse, to give it more weight against slippage, before releasing the mouse button.

Comment: Well, changing DPI settings and such was the first thing I had thought about, but that didn't really help. This is supposedly a good mouse, too. I also use my mouse for gaming, actually, not image editing, so I don't have an extra hand to spare a finger to keep my mouse nice and still :c

Answer (score 1):

Use your thumb and ring finger as sort of adjustable, retractable "mouse feet": keep them up when you need fast and wide mouse movements, put them slightly down to the mouse pad for additional friction when you need smaller and more precise mouse movements, jam them into the mouse pad while squeezing the mouse tight when you need no mouse movements at all. I've once heard about this "technique" from some youtube gamer explaining how to aim more efficiently in 3D shooters, although by that time I've been using my mouse like that intuitively for several years already, so perhaps "technique" is too big of a word for that, but still it may be not completely obvious to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You answered:

> changing DPI settings and such was the first thing I had thought about, but that didn't really help

However, the (other) answer told you about changing the **sensitivity**, not the DPI.

> I use my mouse for gaming, actually, not image editing

Here is your conflict: the classical "speed vs. accuracy". As you were told, decreasing sensitivity (speed) would enable you to stop your mouse more precisely. At the cost of reaching your destination in a longer time.

I have to assume that you have to adjust the mouse settings until you get the best out of them (you should have a more complex control panel for it, compared with a standard cheap mouse). After you get there, you need more practicing using the mouse better - aka to become a better gamer.